# PushNotifications - iOS, Does iOS app requires to be installed firebase framework for fcm notifications

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

My server is moving away from APNS as it is getting depreciated so they are migrating to use firebase, so my app needs a firebase framework or will it work without the framework?

Comment: Is APNS deprecated ? Can you provide relevant link ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to [add the Firebase Cloud Messaging SDK to your iOS app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#add-sdks) to receive messages through FCM.

Comment: Does it really require to install the firebase in client-side I thought it is from server-side and server require only device ID

Comment: The client needs to include an SDK to be able to receive the messages, in the way described in the documentation. I'm still not sure why you downvote an answer that quite literally answers your question.